# JavaFX 2.2: How to set SimpleBooleanProperty value to null?

Tags: java, javafx-2

If I do so:

```
BooleanProperty b = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
b.setValue(null);
System.out.println(b.getValue());
```

I receive output:

```
false
```

How to set `SimpleBooleanProperty` value to `null`? Set `SimpleBooleanProperty` to `null` (`BooleanProperty b = null;`) is bad idea, because I will use binding.

**I founded the way:**

```
ObjectProperty<Boolean> b = new SimpleObjectProperty<Boolean>(null);
System.out.println(b.getValue());
```

Works fine.

**I can't answer on mine questions, so I put it here, sorry.**

Comment: Why would you want to set the value of a `boolean` property to `null`?

Comment: @mre I need 3 states: true, false, undetermined. I want to set `Boolean` value to `null`, not `boolean`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SimpleBooleanProperty` is a wrapper around a `boolean` (primitive) - null values are automatically set to the default (false) value.

If you want to allow `null` values, you can use an `ObjectProperty<Boolean> b = new SimpleObjectProperty<> ();`. The drawback is that you lose the default boolean bindings.

Alternatively, you could create a custom class that overrides the existing setValue implementation, but that could prove somewhat complex because it relies on the `set(boolean)` method which obviously can't accept `null`...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to set the value to `null`. Look at the `BooleanProperty#setValue` implementation,

```
public void setValue(Boolean paramBoolean)
{
    set(paramBoolean == null ? false : paramBoolean.booleanValue());
}
```

This is exactly the behavior you're seeing.